# How to fix the Feeds import error when trying to import a price field?

Tags: ubercart, feeds, importing-exporting

I have a little problem with [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module, I read a lot on forums how to fix this error but I can't find a fix...

I'm importing products to the shop, this module can import thing pretty well but when I add `list_price` or `sell_price` to the mapping the import is stuck.

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect decimal value: '' for
>   column 'list_price' at row 1

Yes I use CSV files, with `utf8 encoding`.

Don't know why I get this error I just write into the column for the price: 20.10

```
array(
  'név' => '100% BEEF Concentrate 1000g',
  'cikkszám' => '1',
  'description' => 'Tartalom',
  'image' => 'scitec_100_beef_concentrate_1000g_caramel_vanilla.png',
  'catalog' => 'Proteíny',
  'gyártók' => 'Scitec Nutrition',
  'nyelv' => 'sk',
  'súly' => '1000',
  'mértékegység' => 'g',
  'listázási ár' => '21.00',
  'akció' => 'uncheck',
  'kiemelt' => 'uncheck',
  'újdonság' => 'check',
)
```

Is this possible to fix somehow?

Another small question is that how can I check and uncheck chechboxes with feeds? What should I write into the CSV column?

Comment: Can you check the SQL query that it generates? You could try to check SQL queries in mysql.log

Answer (score 1):

you should remove single quotes form decimal value and replace uncheck/check to false/true based on value.

Comment: what do you mean "single quotes ?"  like 21 ? its not working... 

i tried like this :  
21 - not working 
21.0 - not working 
21.00 - not working 
If i leave the column empty i get this error too..

Comment: You need to edit the my.cnf MySQL configuration file on your Windows box and replace the following line:     sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

with:


#sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

Comment: i found the my.cnf file but i dont have this line inside it, can i add this anywhere ?